# iOS popViewController does not free memory and dealloc not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I have some problem with memory management under ARC. When I popViewController in my app, none of them frees memory, and sometimes viewcontroller's dealloc is not called. Even when dealloc called, memory is not still freed. So I am asking what will take memory even viewController's dealloc method is called? And what will cause dealloc not to be called? Few possible is animation, delegate? Anything else?

Answer (score 5):

If dealloc is not called, some object has a strong reference to the view controller. You need to inspect your code and look for strong reference cycles.

Don't expect your memory to decrease by the amount it increased when you pushed the view. iOS caches lots of things in memory to improve performance, like images, string literals, etc. Just make sure *you're* not hanging on to objects for longer than you need them.

Comment: Thank you !! So if dealloc is called, does it mean that memory management is alright? I have a viewController which has an AVCaptureSession object, dealloc is called but after push and pop that ViewController for 4-5 times, memory is triple, and takes longer for later pushes. What about that? Any idea, I need to free other object in the viewController as well?

Comment: You typically don't need to free other objects inside the view controller.  Because only the view controller has references to these objects, they will be automatically deallocated after your view controller is deallocated.

Comment: There's nothing specifically different about `AVCaptureSession` in terms of memory management.  Just make sure there aren't objects that all point to each other in that view controller.  If you want help looking at it, I would suggest posting a new question specifically about that view controller, and include all of its relevant code (or, ideally, try to reproduce the issue in a small sample project).

Comment: I found out the problem, AVCaptureSession was the problem, I need to add into the 3rd party library a method closeSession which remove all inputs in the session before I go back. Thank you.

Comment: @TungVo If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct using the checkbox icon to the left of my answer.  This will stop your question from appearing as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 9 provides a great tool for finding that kind of issues. It is called: "**[Debug Memory Graph](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-identifying-memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-e84f097b9d15)**".
Using it you can find your leaked object by class type and you can see clearly who holds a strong reference to it, by releasing it from there solves your problem.

[**See more info about how to use it**](https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-identifying-memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-e84f097b9d15)